# Understanding and dealing with a probability problem

Tags: probability

Given a sequence of $N$ elements : $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$,which respresent the frequency of the numbers from $1$ to $N$, and a number $X\leq N$, compute the probability that when picking $m$ elements from the $x_1+x_2+...+x_n$ possibilities, the number $X$ appears at least once .

This is the complete text of the problem, yet I can't really understand it,  let alone find a solution . Can anyone help ?

Comment: I find that when I don't understand a problem, a good first step in general is to substitute values for the variables. For example, you could suppose that $N=3$, $X=2$, and $m=1$.

Answer (score 0):

HINTS:
The probability that $X$ appears on the first go is $\frac{x_X}{x_1+...+x_N}$.
What is the probability that $X$ does not appear on the first go?
What is the probability that $X$ does not appear on any of the $m$ goes?
What is the probability that $X$ appears at least once?

Answer (score 0):

You've got $x_1+...+x_N$ slips of paper in a case, exactly $x_i$ with the title $i$. You take off m slips from the case (I think it is supposed that you take off each slip with the same chance). You have to compute the chance of the taking off at least one slip with the title $X$.